# Set memory limit to Valgrind

Tags: out-of-memory, mips, valgrind

I'm trying to run Valgrind on a mips32 machine in order to detect a memory leak. The total available memory is 32MB (without SWAP). The problem is that Valgrind itself is not able to allocate the amount of memory that he needs and always generates an "out of memory" error.

```
root@babidi# valgrind --leak-check=yes grep -r "foo" /etc/config/
==9392== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9392== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9392== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9392== Command: grep -r foo /etc/config/
==9392== 
==9392== 
==9392==     Valgrind's memory management: out of memory:
==9392==        initialiseSector(TC)'s request for 27597024 bytes failed.
==9392==        20516864 bytes have already been allocated.
==9392==     Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.
==9392== 
==9392==     There are several possible reasons for this.
==9392==     - You have some kind of memory limit in place.  Look at the
==9392==       output of 'ulimit -a'.  Is there a limit on the size of
==9392==       virtual memory or address space?
==9392==     - You have run out of swap space.
==9392==     - Valgrind has a bug.  If you think this is the case or you are
==9392==     not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==9392==     Please note that programs can take substantially more memory than
==9392==     normal when running under Valgrind tools, eg. up to twice or
==9392==     more, depending on the tool.  On a 64-bit machine, Valgrind
==9392==     should be able to make use of up 32GB memory.  On a 32-bit
==9392==     machine, Valgrind should be able to use all the memory available
==9392==     to a single process, up to 4GB if that's how you have your
==9392==     kernel configured.  Most 32-bit Linux setups allow a maximum of
==9392==     3GB per process.
==9392== 
==9392==     Whatever the reason, Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.
```

What I'm wondering is if it is possible to limit the amount of memory that Valgrind allocates. I tried playing with --max-stacksize and --max-stackframe but the result is always the same.

Comment: Checkout this post on increasing the memory limit for Valgrind: http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/27779126/

You may be able to lower the limit doing basically the same thing.

Comment: 32MB is awfully small. Assuming the OS and other processes need some memory, and your app needs some for itself that doesn't really leave a lot for valgrind to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, 32MB is not much. It must cover the OS and some other necessary processes. When you analyze a program with Valgrind/Memcheck, it requires more than twice as much memory than the program would do by itself. This is because Memcheck stores shadow values for every allocated bit, so that it can recognize uninitialized variables.

I think that the best solution would be to compile your program for your desktop computer and run Memcheck from there. If you have leaks, uninitialized variables, etc in your program, you will have them on your desktop computer as well.

If you are curious how your program will behave on the MIPS, analyze it with other Valgrind tools, such as Massif (measuring heap over time) and Cachegrind (cache performance). Those are much more light-weigth than Memcheck.